# Convert CMD cURL to PHP

Tags: php, curl

I try to curl [this url](http://b2b.sriwijayaair.co.id/SJ-Eticket/login.php?action=in) and this is curl cmd command using copy as curl in chrome :

```
curl "http://b2b.sriwijayaair.co.id/SJ-Eticket/login.php?action=in" -H "Pragma: no-cache" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Cookie: PHPSESSID=nupsnjthtmgedjcuguh80667v4; _ga=GA1.3.1626934475.1455171426" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --compressed
```

I got the results i expected when using cmd, but when i try convert to php the result is not same

PHP Code :

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.1) Gecko/20060111 Firefox/1.5.0.1');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Pragma: no-cache',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Cache-Control: no-cache',
        'Cookie: PHPSESSID=nupsnjthtmgedjcuguh80667v4; _ga=GA1.3.1626934475.1455171426'
    ));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://b2b.sriwijayaair.co.id/SJ-Eticket/login.php?action=in');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

print_r($result);
```

Result : 
[image]

What i miss ?

Comment: *"the result is not same"* Details like this often help us. Stab in the dark: Your curl command has a `Cookie`, which your PHP does not. You also have a different user-agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to send all the headers as chrome does.

Also you are missing cookie in your header. Try with this header.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Cookie: PHPSESSID=nupsnjthtmgedjcuguh80667v4; _ga=GA1.3.1626934475.1455171426'
));
```

Note: This cookie you have copied from your browser. So it will expire soon.

Comment: It mean your cookie has expired. Your same curl command on question should not work now until you refresh the cookie.

Comment: Yeaahh, solved with just send `Pragma`, `Accept`, `Cache-Control` as header and use same user agent with chrome curl, thanks